# PHP Array Printing

Tags: php, mysql

I have some strings from my MySQL data base. Two of them used in this question are:

```
$preset = "Because we to and "
$response = "want survive prosper improve"
$order = "00101101"
```

I want to print the preset and response text on the page in the order laid out by `$order` (0 = preset, 1 = response).

So far I have this code:

```
#Variables
$responsewords = explode(" ",$response);
$presetwords = explode(" ", $preset);
$orderexplode = str_split($order, 1);
#Doing Things
foreach($orderexplode as $o)
{
    for ($rsw = 0; $rsw <= $noresponse; $rsw++ )
    {
        switch ($o)
        {
            case 0:
                echo "<br>"."<label>".
                    $presetwords[$rsw].
                    "</label>"." ";
                break;
            case 1:
                echo "<input type='text' class='form-control'".
                    " placeholder=".$responsewords[$rsw].">";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that this code prints [this](https://gyazo.com/87044042f3ee041594bce2f0351d6342), where basically it prints out the whole string, but not separated into separate words for each 0 or 1. The outcome I am looking for is [this](https://gyazo.com/87acbdf95844db6088695bca1aad5e17)
(excuse my inspect element).

Comment: First of all: what is `$noresponse`?

Comment: $noresponse     = $row['noresponse'];
 $nopreset       = $row['nopreset'];
are two other sql coulumns they define how many preset words there are and how many boxes there are.

Comment: Please include the essential information in your question: current output and expected output.

Comment: @NathanLeadill ok, but what represent it? You perform a `for` loop with it at limit, so I imagine it is a number, but what they means? it is the `$order` len?

Comment: It is the amount of responses that question uses.

Comment: @NathanLeadill I don't understand its relation with your code. BTW, I have posted an answer without using it: let me know if they works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$preset = "Because we to and ";
 $response = "want survive prosper improve";
 $order = "00101101";
$orderexplode = str_split($order, 1);
 $responsewords = explode(" ",$response);
    $presetwords = explode(" ", $preset);

$i =0; $k=0;
foreach($orderexplode as $o)
        {

            switch ($o) 
             {
                case 0:
                    echo "<label>".$presetwords[$i]."</label>"." ";
                    $i++;
                break;
                case 1:
                    echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder=".$responsewords[$k]."><br>";
                    $k++;
                break;
             }

        }
```

Comment: Would there be a way to make boxes and words go on the same line?

Comment: If you want everything in one line, just remove <br>

Comment: @NathanLeadill word order is not work or text is one line not working.

Comment: @Jitendra Never mind Fixed it, If i wanted to use this in a form (ill link you my new question 2 secs)

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_shift()` and `sprintf` you can shorter your code.

The first part remain untouched:

```
$preset        = "Because we to and ";
$response      = "want survive prosper improve";
$order         = "00101101";
```

Then, we create an array with exploded preset at index 0 and exploded response at index 1.
In addition, we create an array with formats (a sort of template) with keys correspondence to previously array. The `%s` will be replaced by single words:

```
$strings = array( explode(" ",$preset), explode(" ", $response) );
$formats = array( '<label>%s</label>', '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="%s">' );

$orderexplode = str_split( $order, 1 );
```

Through a `foreach` loop, we extract single words from `$string` sub-array based on `$orderexplode`, then we output it using `sprintf()` as format:

```
foreach( $orderexplode as $key => $o )
{
    $txt = array_shift( $strings[$o] );
    echo sprintf( $formats[$o], $txt ).PHP_EOL;
}
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/0Du2d)**</kbd>

---

- Read more about [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)
- Read more about [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)